# Reference for how Python handles data?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, integer

I have a list that is <class 'bytes'> that is comprised of a 16-bit PCM value of <class 'int'>. The list is the result of a direct read of a segment of a 16-bit PCM wave file. I then create a numpy array from that built up list to save it as a separate wave file for training but wavfile.write() always fails because the 16-bit PCM data is wrong somehow, such as:

1. `wavfile.write(savepath + 'wave_speechsegment_' + str(wavecnt) + '.wav', sr, nparray.astype(np.int16))` generates a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'z\xfe'` error
2. And trying nparray directly: `wavfile.write(savepath + 'wave_speechsegment_' + str(wavecnt) + '.wav', sr, nparray)` I get `ValueError: Unsupported data type '|S2`

I try to set the list as 16-bit PCM values with:

```
hexval = struct.pack('<BB', val[0], val[1])
waveform.append(hexval)
nparray = np.array(waveform)
```

but when I save the 16-bit PCM values to the numpy file, python reports:

```
nparray is type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>  and nparray[0] is:  b'z\xfe'  and is type:  <class 'numpy.bytes_'>
```

Saving to the numpy array segment to a file produces precisely the data set found for that segment in the source wave file, such as:

```
7A FE DE FE C5 FF 75 00 2F 01 76 01 99 01 55 01 05 01 74 00 05 00 9D FF 79 FF 65 FF 8C FF C9 FF
```

Can someone point me to information about how python deals with data, so that I can keep my 16-bit PCM data as 16-bit PCM data?

Comment: I think you want `struct.unpack` when conveying the data into the numpy array?

Comment: Using hexval = struct.unpack('<h', val) produces: hexval is: (-390,) and is type: <class 'tuple'> whereas pack produces: hexval is: b'z\xfe' and is type: <class 'bytes'>. There is a difference between the result depending on which is used. The problem may be due to the use of pack and unpack and the different types produced.

Comment: Also, I noticed that when saved in a file and opened in HxD, struct.unpack pads my original data with either xFFFF or x0000 depending on whether it is positive or negative, such as: 7A FE FF FF or 2F 01 00 00. According to struct's page, "h" is "short, integer, 2", so why the padding? Pack does not pad. I guess I have to go through the source to figure out how it handles data.

Comment: You need to keep track of which variable has data in what form; make a table in your notebook or whiteboard or a piece of paper or something

Comment: I was and found that Python seems to want to work with 32 bits. I convert the 16-bit value b'z\xfe' to int with hexval = int.from_bytes(hexval, "little", signed="True") and this produces -390  of  <class 'int'> that is actually the hex value 7A FE FF FF. This is accepted by wavfile.write(filename, sr, nparray.astype(np.int16)) and produces a 16-bit PCM file that Audacity opens as a wavefile. So, the padding seems normal, but I have been reading through library source, but haven't found why Python doesn't just handle 16-bit PCM values straight away.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [73]: astr = b'z\xfe'
In [74]: type(astr)
Out[74]: bytes
In [75]: len(astr)
Out[75]: 2             # 2 bytes
```

This is not a `list`.  It's a string, more specifically a byte string, as opposed to the default (for Python 3) unicode string.

An array, created from such as string, will have a `S` dtype:

```
In [76]: arr= np.array(astr)
In [77]: arr
Out[77]: array(b'z\xfe', dtype='|S2')
In [78]: arr= np.array(astr+astr+astr)   # + joins strings into one
In [79]: arr
Out[79]: array(b'z\xfez\xfez\xfe', dtype='|S6')
```

The `data-buffer` of the array contains those bytes.  And can be `view` as other compatible dtypes.

```
In [87]: arr= np.array([astr+astr+astr])
In [88]: arr
Out[88]: array([b'z\xfez\xfez\xfe'], dtype='|S6')
In [89]: arr.view('S1')
Out[89]: array([b'z', b'\xfe', b'z', b'\xfe', b'z', b'\xfe'], dtype='|S1')
In [94]: arr.view('int16')
Out[94]: array([-390, -390, -390], dtype=int16)
In [95]: arr.view('uint16')
Out[95]: array([65146, 65146, 65146], dtype=uint16)
In [98]: arr.view('>i2')
Out[98]: array([31486, 31486, 31486], dtype=int16)
```

Comment: PEP 358 states "A bytes object stores a mutable sequence of integers that are in the range 0 to 255. Unlike string objects, indexing a bytes object returns an integer." Unpacking the just read 2-byte value produces a <class 'tuple'> and saves the numpy array values in a numpy array file wrong, as a 4-byte value: 7A FE FF FF while packing its two byte value produces a <class 'bytes'> type and saves the value correctly as a 2-byte value: 7A FE. How to control Python's default data typing to force a dtype of int16 such that wavefile.write (see 1 in original post) will use it?